# hibernate bug: How to keep Hibernate sql where condition order obey the declared order?

Tags: sql, hibernate, where-clause, composite-primary-key

I have a class `Student`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student{
  @EmbeddedId 
  private Id id;
  //other property omit

  @Embeddable
  public static class Id implements Serializable{
   @Column(name="last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name="first_name")
   private String firstName;

 }

}
```

I used hibernate to find a student by id, but I found that the generated sql `where` clause is what I don't expect. I want to generate the sql like `select * from student where last_name = ? and first_name = ?`, but the generated sql looks like `select * from student where first_name = ? last_name = ?`.

I want the generated sql `where` clause expression order to obey the proper order. Does anyone know how to generate such sql when I query a entity by composite id?

Comment: The two queries are strictly identical. You should worry about something else. Like using functional, mutable, non-unique strings for the ID instead of using an immutable, technical numeric unique ID.

Comment: Please add the code that produces this SQL

Comment: @user2700840 the code that produces this SQL is the Hibernate code. It doesn't care about the order of the fields because the order is meaningless.

Comment: @JBNizet As I understand it's a search by the student. If you want to get the student, you should write some code (Criteria, Query Over, etc)

Comment: Order is totally irrelevant here. It does not affect the changes result at all